# SQL left / right JOIN issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run script below, but always getting NULL values for name field.

```
SELECT u.name AS _user_name, s.name AS _school_name
FROM fwg_files AS f
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_profiles AS up ON up.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN school AS s ON s.id = up.profile_value
```

The problem seems to me in JOIN ON school table, I tried to SELECT s.id and it returns NULL values also. When I change last line to RIGHT JOIN it starts to work, but I can see just the s.name value, the others are NULL

Table fwg_files

```
id  | user_id
240 | 414
241 | 436
```

Table users

```
id  | name
414 | Name 1
436 | Name 2
```

Table user_profiles

```
user_id | profile_value
414     | "6"
436     | "14"
```

Table school

```
id | name

 6 | School 1
14 | School 2
```

Thank you

Comment: Sac: no, I didn't, do you have any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Your profile values should be a foreign key with integer type not with varchar

Comment: I tried to modify last line to LEFT JOIN fad9u_school AS s ON s.id = CAST( up.profile_value AS UNSIGNED ), but stil same result

Comment: try to cast profile value as INT

Comment: I think it is working.. just see this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deea5/2

Output =
_USER_NAME  _SCHOOL_NAME
Name 1   School 1
Name 2   School 2

Comment: I can't change the structure of database - this is default Joomla configuration which could affect other discrepancies, it will be enough to transfer up.profile_value to INT just for the JOIN operation

Comment: Sac: I modified exact values - the problem is in quotation in value - look at your sqlfiddle

Comment: The quotation is a must?

Comment: it's standard DB structure, if I remove it I have to change some other modules CAST( up.profile_value AS INT ) doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the quotations on the `profile_value` column is a must then need to use a mix of `CONVERT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get rid of the quotations in order to be able to do the operation.

Check the following code:

```
SELECT users.name as User, s.name as School
  FROM fwg_files AS ff
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = ff.user_id
  LEFT JOIN user_profiles AS up ON up.user_id = users.id
  LEFT JOIN school AS s ON s.id = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(up.profile_value,'"',-2),UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

And here the [working SQL Fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a598/11) with quotations.